# How to bind a Command to the ItemClick event in MvxListView?

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Channel> Series { get; private set; }

private MvxCommand<Channel> enableClicked;
public ICommand EnableClicked
{
    get
    {
        return enableClicked = enableClicked ??
            new MvxCommand<Channel>(ch => {
                ch.Enabled = !ch.Enabled;
            });
    }
}
```

And my axml looks like:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/serieenable"
    app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Series; ItemClick EnableClicked" />
```

I put a breakpoint on the line `return enableClicked`, which is hit.

If I put a breakpoint on the line `ch.Enabled = !ch.Enabled;`, it is never hit, when I touch a ListView item.

How do I bind a Command to the `ItemClick` event in `MvxListView`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue. Just tried with a small sample with strings:

```
private MvxCommand<string> _clickCommand;
public ICommand ClickCommand
    => _clickCommand = _clickCommand ?? new MvxCommand<string>(OnClick);

private void OnClick(string item)
{
    Mvx.TaggedTrace("MyVM", $"Item {item} clicked");
}
```

And View:

```
<MvxListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/my_listitem"
    app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; ItemClick ClickCommand" />
```

Triggers and works just fine.

Comment: Can you please share my_listitem?